# Change IFrame Source if page doen't load in IFrame using Javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a code like this:-

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="http://www.abc.com" target="iframe">ABC</a>
        <iframe name="iframe"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want this functionality:-
If there is an error in loading the page if IFrame, than it change the IFrame source to other url. I want this for both Firefox and IE using javascript